# What interfaces are implemented by a class?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I think it is a simple stuff, but I cannot find it.

Are there any easy way to know what interfaces a class implements? Directly or in its ancestor classes.

I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro without commercial addons.

Thanks.

Comment: @Hans: Implemented interfaces are listed in the "Base Types" folder if the "Show Base Types" option is checked in the Object Browser toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to open `Class View` window (menu View -> Class View) and see it in a graphical representation under Base Types:

[image]

Also, make sure you've installed [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) because it allows you to see base / derived types, references, etc. through very handy interactive tool tips:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you asked, but you can press F12 on a class name (right click -> Go to definition) and then just look at the `class Foo : IBar` line.

Answer (score 2):

You can see this in the Object Browser (under the "Base Types" folder). You will need to have the "Show Base Types" option checked though:
[image]

Comment: I think Denis answer is a more right way of get the base types.  Thanks for your answer.