# Check if an object implements an interface

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Is there any way I can quickly check if an object implements a specific interface in Visual Studio?

**Example:**

```
interface IFirstInterface : ISecondInterface
{
}

interface ISecondInterface
{
    void DoStuff();
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
class MyClass : IFirstInterface
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // ISecondInterface implementation
    }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
var instance = new MyClass();
```

When writing *My Code* it would be nice to do a quick check to see whether or not `MyClass` implements `ISecondInterface`. Is this possible?

**Note:** I'm not talking about doing this via code - just via the Visual Studio UI. I am also using Resharper in case that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>H</kbd>. It will take you to [Hierarchies](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Windows__Type_Hierarchy_Window.html) window of resharper. It has all the features you're asking about.

Check out the toolbar over there for different kind of view.

Comment: Actually it's Ctrl + E, H

Answer (score 1):

If I recall, [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) lets you do this as seen here [What interfaces are implemented by a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285029/what-interfaces-are-implemented-by-a-class) Not sure about resharper because I don't use it.

Also, the object browser should let you see this.

Answer (score 1):

You could check this via pressing `Ctrl+U` (Go to base symbols, R#). If the class has more than one base symbol R# will show you a window with all of base symbols.

Answer (score 0):

How would this check look like? Display a tooltip?

You could write:

```
 ISecondInterface instance = new MyClass();
```

This will not compile/display error help, if it doesn't implement the interface.

Or if you need the type of instance to be `MyClass`:

```
 void AssureItImplements<T>(T dummy){};

 ...
 var instance = new MyClass();
 AssureItImplements<ISecondInterface>(instance);
```

These are ways you could do this in code, just in case someone else finds it useful.

```
 var implementsInterface1 = typeof(ISecondInterface).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType());
 var implementsInterface2 = instance as ISecondInterface != null;
 var implementsInterface3 = instance is ISecondInterface;
```